# SQL Server query with union and different order by to each section?

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I've searched here on the site. and there are many version of answers to this question. But couldn't find what I was looking for for this specific question :

lets say that xxx,yyy,zzz has 1 column, 3 rows:

```
1   
2   
3   

SELECT a FROM xxx  order by a asc
UNION 
SELECT f FROM yyy order by f desc
UNION 
SELECT t FROM zzz order by t asc
```

So the desired result set is:

```
1
2
3
3
2
1
1
2
3
```

There is an error of incorrect syntax near UNION.

I'm aware of the order problem with union (and know how to solve it only if an overall ORDER BY is required.)

Question :

how can I get my desired output?

Comment: Can you display an example of the desired result set?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, you should wait for more answers and then choose the best one, thanks for your time.

Comment: @Md.EliasHossain I accept your comment. thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to apply a *single* order by clause to the *entire* union, or else the ordering isn't well defined:

```
SELECT a,1 as Pos,a as Ord from xxx
UNION ALL
SELECT f,2,-f from yyy
UNION ALL
SELECT t,3,t from zzz
ORDER BY Pos,Ord
```

However, the `-f` might feel like a dirty trick to achieve the opposite ordering (or may not be entirely what you want if `NULL`s are included), so you could also do:

```
SELECT a,1 as Pos,a as OrdAsc,0 as OrdDesc from xxx
UNION ALL
SELECT f,2,0,f from yyy
UNION ALL
SELECT t,3,t,0 from zzz
ORDER BY Pos asc,Ord asc,OrdDesc desc
```

---

I'm unclear on why you don't think it answers your question - perhaps because of the additional columns in the result set? If so, you can arrange for the whole `UNION` to be in a subquery:

```
create table #xxx (a int not null)
create table #yyy (f int not null)
create table #zzz (t int not null)
insert into #xxx (a) select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3
insert into #yyy (f) select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3
insert into #zzz (t) select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3

SELECT a FROM (
SELECT a,1 as Pos,a as Ord from #xxx
UNION ALL
SELECT f,2,-f from #yyy
UNION ALL
SELECT t,3,t from #zzz
) t
ORDER BY Pos,Ord
```

results:

```
a
----
1
2
3
3
2
1
1
2
3
```

Comment: This wont give me : **123321123** ....it will give me the overall order which doesnt help me ....

Comment: @RoyiNamir - can you be clearer on why this *isn't* an answer to your question?

Comment: because im stupid enough not to understand your lovely solution ...http://i.stack.imgur.com/uuOkM.jpg... now let me digest what you have done here :) thank you.

Comment: again, Thank you very much for the effort :)

Answer (score 1):

Things to keep in mind while `UNIONing`:

- `UNION` allows you to create a `RESULTSET`with same type data from different `SELECT` statement.
- The `RESULTSET` is generated with the column name of leading(first) `SELECT` statement.
- For other `SELECT` statement columns data type should be matched according to the leading(first) `SELECT` statement.
- For `ORDERing`, its applied on the `RESULTSET`, consequently in case of `UNION`, it only allows `ORDER BY` at the last `SELECT` statement but takes column name according to leading(first) `SELECT` statement, so below example is true:
- **Finally**, since in the `RESULTSET` for `UNIONing` with different tables/sources aggregates all data into a column(according to first(leading) `SELECT` statement), so you can not apply `ASC` and `DESC` for same column.

**Right**

```
SELECT a FROM xxx 
UNION 
SELECT f FROM yyy
UNION 
SELECT t FROM zzz order by a asc
```

**Wrong**: *according to you*

```
SELECT a FROM xxx 
UNION 
SELECT f FROM yyy
UNION 
SELECT t FROM zzz order by a asc, a desc
```